# Is a repeated measures Poisson regression for rates the correct test, and how to perform in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, biostatistics, poisson-regression

I am studying wildlife use of overpasses across three seasons and I believe a Poisson regression for rates with repeated measures is the correct analysis to use, but I am not sure how to include repeated measures in the R code, and I want to make sure this analysis correctly addresses my research question!

Study design:
I placed remote cameras at 40 overpass crossing structures to capture photos of wildlife crossing a canal over one year. The year is broken into three seasons (hot-dry, hot-wet, and cool-wet). The three seasons are each different lengths (hot-dry: 61 days, hot-wet: 123 days, cool-wet: 182 days).

Research question:
Does crossing frequency vary among the three seasons?

Data:
Each site is associated with a total number of crossings for a given species in each season. Each season is associated with a different length of time. Below is an example of how my data is set up. In reality I have 40 sites, and the # crossings displayed below are made up.

| Site | Season | # crossings | Active days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Hot-Dry | 10 | 61 |
| B | Hot-Dry | 12 | 61 |
| C | Hot-Dry | 16 | 61 |
| A | Hot-Wet | 22 | 123 |
| B | Hot-Wet | 25 | 123 |
| C | Hot-Wet | 33 | 123 |
| A | Cool-Wet | 67 | 182 |
| B | Cool-Wet | 70 | 182 |
| C | Cool-Wet | 81 | 182 |

Because I am using count data, I chose a Poisson regression. Because I need to account for different lengths of time in each season, I decided on a Poisson regression for rates (I included an offset for active days). I know my data are not independent because I am sampling the same sites in each season, so I believe I need to add in a repeated measures function. I am performing the analyses in RStudio.

The code (without the repeated measures function) I have used is:

```r
model <- glm(Crossings ~ Season + offset(logdays), 
    family = poisson(link = "log"), data = data)
```

My questions are:

1. Does this seem like the correct approach?
2. How do I add a repeated measures function into the model?

As a note, I have also looked into the Friedman Test and that is a backup option. For that test, I would calculate the crossing rate for each site in every season (# crossings/active days) and test crossing rate ~ season with site as the blocking variable. Maybe this makes more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poisson model is a good way to start with count data. Sometimes the variance around the model predictions is greater than what you might expect from a Poisson model, so you might need to move to a negative binomial model or use a "quasi-Poisson" model that adjusts for the extra variance. There are many pages about those alternatives on this site.

A simple way to incorporate the repeated measurements per Site would be to treat Site as a random effect in a mixed-effects Poisson model. With the R [`lme4` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lme4) you would write a similar model to what you have:

```
model <- glmer(Crossings ~ Season + offset(logdays) + (1|Site), 
              family = poisson(link = "log"), data = data)
```

The `(1|Site)` term allows for different baseline rates among sites, modeled with a Gaussian distribution. That uses up a lot fewer degrees of freedom than trying to treat 40 sites as individual fixed effects.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the reply. I ran the code for a species and am happy with the results so far. However, there is over dispersion in the model. As you suggested, I tried to run a quassi-Poisson model with the same line of code, but with family = quassipoisson. Unfortunately I received an error that quassi families cannot be used with glmer. Do I need to use a different package?

Comment: Disregard the previous comment! I was able to figure out how to obtain the quassi-poisson estimates using this website (https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#fitting-models-with-overdispersion) that had been referenced in other similar questions. Thank you again for the help!